# partykit::mob() + mlogit: `Error no suitable fitting function specified`

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, party

I am trying to fit a conditional logit using `mlogit::mlogit()` at the end leaves of the tree generated by the [MOB algorithm](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/106186008X319331) `partykit::mob()`. Apparently, it cannot be made directly using the `partykit::mob()` function (below my attempts). However, I found the [LORET](https://rdrr.io/rforge/loret/) algorithm, but I couldn't find any documentation with examples, so I tried guessing which function I need from the source code, but unfortunately, I couldn't make it work.

Do you know how (1) where I could find examples for the LORET library and (2) if it is possible to use the `partykit:mob()` function to work together with `mlogit::mlogit`? Thanks in advance.

---

#### Example data

For illustration, please gently consider the following data. It represents data from 5 individuals (`id_ind` ) that choose among 3 alternatives (`altern`). Each of the five individuals chose three times; hence we have 15 choice situations (`id_choice`). Each alternative is represented by two generic attributes (`x1` and `x2`), and the choices are registered in `y` (`1` if selected, `0` otherwise). Finally, `z1` is a candidate partition variable.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id_ind id_choice altern           x1          x2 y
1       1         1      1  1.586788801  0.11887832 1
2       1         1      2 -0.937965347  1.15742493 0
3       1         1      3 -0.511504401 -1.90667519 0
4       1         2      1  1.079365680 -0.37267925 0
5       1         2      2 -0.009203032  1.65150370 1
6       1         2      3  0.870474033 -0.82558651 0
7       1         3      1 -0.638604013 -0.09459502 0
8       1         3      2 -0.071679538  1.56879334 0
9       1         3      3  0.398263302  1.45735788 1
10      2         4      1  0.291413453 -0.09107974 0
11      2         4      2  1.632831160  0.92925495 0
12      2         4      3 -1.193272276  0.77092623 1
13      2         5      1  1.967624379 -0.16373709 1
14      2         5      2 -0.479859282 -0.67042130 0
15      2         5      3  1.109780885  0.60348187 0
16      2         6      1 -0.025834772 -0.44004183 0
17      2         6      2 -1.255129594  1.10928280 0
18      2         6      3  1.309493274  1.84247199 1
19      3         7      1  1.593558740 -0.08952151 0
20      3         7      2  1.778701074  1.44483791 1
21      3         7      3  0.643191170 -0.24761157 0
22      3         8      1  1.738820924 -0.96793288 0
23      3         8      2 -1.151429915 -0.08581901 0
24      3         8      3  0.606695064  1.06524268 1
25      3         9      1  0.673866953 -0.26136206 0
26      3         9      2  1.176959443  0.85005871 1
27      3         9      3 -1.568225496 -0.40002252 0
28      4        10      1  0.516456176 -1.02081089 1
29      4        10      2 -1.752854918 -1.71728381 0
30      4        10      3 -1.176101700 -1.60213536 0
31      4        11      1 -1.497779616 -1.66301234 0
32      4        11      2 -0.931117325  1.50128532 1
33      4        11      3 -0.455543630 -0.64370825 0
34      4        12      1  0.894843784 -0.69859139 0
35      4        12      2 -0.354902281  1.02834859 0
36      4        12      3  1.283785176 -1.18923098 1
37      5        13      1 -1.293772990 -0.73491317 0
38      5        13      2  0.748091387  0.07453705 1
39      5        13      3 -0.463585127  0.64802031 0
40      5        14      1 -1.946438667  1.35776140 0
41      5        14      2 -0.470448172 -0.61326604 1
42      5        14      3  1.478763383 -0.66490028 0
43      5        15      1  0.588240775  0.84448489 1
44      5        15      2  1.131731049 -1.51323232 0
45      5        15      3  0.212145247 -1.01804594 0
")
df$z1 <- rnorm(n= nrow(df),mean = 0,sd = 1)
```

---

### `mlogit` + `partykit::mob()`

```
library(mlogit)
library(partykit)
mo <-  mlogit(formula =  y ~ x1 + x2 , 
              data =  df,
              idx  =  c("id_choice", "altern"))
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept):2  (Intercept):3             x1             x2  
#        0.036497       0.293254       0.821173       1.062794

mlogit_function <-  function(y, x,
                             offset = NULL,
                             ...){ mlogit(y ~  x ,
                                          data =  df)}
formula <-  y ~ x1 + x2 | z1 
mob(formula = formula,
    data    = df,
    fit     = mlogit_function,
    control = mob_control(minsize = 10, 
                          alpha = 0.01))
# Error in mob(formula = formula, data = df, fit = mlogit_function, control = mob_control(minsize = 10,  
# no suitable fitting function specified
```

---

### `mlogit` + `loret::multinomtree()`

This function runs the tree, but it is not what I want because there is a missing constant for alternative 2.

```
loret::multinomtree(formula = formula,
                    data = df)
# Model-based recursive partitioning (NULL)
# Model formula:
#   y ~ x1 + x2 | z1
# 
# Fitted party:
#   [1] root: n = 45
# 1:(Intercept)          1:x1          1:x2 
# -1.1046317     0.7663315     1.0418296  
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    0
# Number of terminal nodes: 1
# Number of parameters per node: 3
# Objective function: 22.62393
```

---

### `mlogit` + `loret::clmtree()`

```
loret::clmtree(formula = formula,
               data = df)
# Error in clm.fit.default(y = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,  : 
#                                  is.list(y) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete solution but hopefully enough feedback to get you started:

- It is important to distinguish so-called "conditional logit" models with alternative-specific variables (which you are interested in) and classic "multinomial logit models" with only subject-specific (or individual-specific) variables. `mlogit::mlogit()` can fit both (and also mixed versions) while `nnet::multinom()` only supports the latter.
- For fitting conditional logit models you could have the data in long vs. wide form. You specify your data in long form and also have a splitting variable `z1` that is alternative-specific. This means that data from the same individual could end up in different nodes of the tree which would be rather awkward.
- Instead it would be better to have the data in wide form so that each row corresponds to an individual and then you could only consider individual-specific variables for splitting. This would also match the view of the `$gradient` element of a fitted`mlogit` object which provides the individual-specific gradient contributions. (This is what `sandwich::estfun()` extracts which in turns is the essential information for `partykit::mob()`.)
- It might also be possible to do sensible recursive partitioning based on alternative-specific variables but I find it hard to see what kind of models this would yield and what these would mean. In any case, you then would have to write your own code to extract the `estfun` from the fitted-model object that provides the fully disaggregated alternative-specific gradient contributions.
- The `loret` package is somewhat unfinished and hasn't been updated in quite a while. Hence, I would not recommend using it "in production" at the moment. Also `nnet::multinom()` (underlying `loret::multinomtree()`) does not fit the model you need (as mentioned above) and `ordinal::clm()` (underlying `loret::clmtree()`) is for a completely different model.
- One specific aspect that we wanted to build into `loret` but did not finish yet, is automatic detection of (quasi-)complete separation in logistic models and handling it appropriately in the tree.
- Your `mlogit` + `partykit::mob()` approach does not work because the fitting function does not have the right interface (as you are correctly informed). See `vignette("mob", package = "partykit")` for the two supported interfaces.
- To write an appropriate interface you need to make sure that you have all the variables you need in each subset. Note that the response variable plus regressor matrix is not enough for this but you need the index variables as well! I would recommend to include these variables either through the `y` variables or the `x` variables of the formula specified for `partykit::mob()`. In `mob_control()` you can then set `ytype = "data.frame"` and `xtype = "data.frame"`. Then both `y` and `x` are provided as `data.frame` objects and can be combined again prior to calling `mlogit::mlogit()`. The `formula` and `idx` arguments for `mlogit()` have to be provided in some way then. In the example below I have hard-coded them.

Illustration based on your example: You can set up a model-fitting function `my_fit()` that expects `y` and `x` to be data frames and then uses the `formula = y ~ x1 + x2` and `idx = c("id_choice", "altern")` to fit the `mlogit()` model.

```
my_fit <- function(y, x = NULL, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, ...) {
  mlogit::mlogit(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = cbind(y, x), idx = c("id_choice", "altern"))
}
```

To specifify the tree you then need to pass all required variables for the `mlogit()` model through the `x` variables of the `mob()` formula:

```
tr <- mob(y ~ x1 + x2 + id_choice + altern | z1, data = df, fit = my_fit,
  control = mob_control(ytype = "data.frame", xtype = "data.frame"))
```

Superficially, this works. At least it fits the desired model in the root node as you can see by checking `coef(tree)`. However, the only reason it works is that it does not even try to do any partitioning as the sample size is judged to be too small compared to the number of parameters.

But when you additionally set `minsize = 10` in `mob_control()` then the partitioning process will fail. The reason for this is that the splitting variable is of length 45 but the gradient/estfun from `mlogit()` is only of length 15. This is the long alternative-specific format vs. the short individual-specific format.

Thus, to make things work you have to use the data in wide form and then adapt the `mob()` formula and the `mlogit()` call inside `my_fit()` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for this long and clear explanation. I have managed to "tweak" the `partykit::mob()` in the file [`modelparty.R`](https://github.com/cran/partykit/blob/master/R/modelparty.R) function to work with `mlogit()` in long format. In general, I compress the data to a one-row-per-choice-set just before performing the stability test with the  [mob_grow_fluctests()](https://github.com/cran/partykit/blob/master/R/modelparty.R#L550) function and altered the internal [fit()](https://github.com/cran/partykit/blob/master/R/modelparty.R#L17) function to work with mlogit.

Comment: However, I will not claim my solution to be a very 'elegant' one; and unfortunately, I am not sure how to share it here for future readers.

Comment: Rather than tweaking `mob()` I would recommend tweaking fitting function supplied to `mob()`, or not? I assume you just need the disaggregated gradient contributions in `estfun`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @AchimZeileis, below I posted an answer that follows your reasoning. Additionally, I have one final question about if it is possible to compute the M-fluctuation tests computed by [`mob_grow_fluctests()`](https://github.com/cran/partykit/blob/master/R/modelparty.R#L550) at the level of individuals (namely using variable `id_ind` with a total of  5 "independent" observations) instead of at the level of choice situations (namely using variable `id_choice` and assuming that there is a total of 15 "independent" observations)

Comment: The motivation of my last question is mainly because I want to account for the fact that multiple answers from the same individual are most likely correlated; hence, assume them as independent is not that realistic, even though the variance-covariance matrix used to compute the empirical fluctuation process is clustered (as we can see from [this line](https://github.com/cran/partykit/blob/06ba66bd8246eca835c67d23f0af95bff9a86c2c/R/modelparty.R#L241) in the source code).

Comment: To be concrete, what I would like to do could be defined in terms of [equation (5)](https://www.zeileis.org/papers/Zeileis+Hothorn+Hornik-2008.pdf) of the original article. Hence, $\hat{J}$ should be a variance-covariance clustered across individuals, which is currently done by the algorithm. Additionally, $n$ should be the number of individuals (5 in the example), not the choice situations (15 in the example). Finally, the cumulative summation of the score functions should be aggregated the level of individuals (by now, it is done at the level of choice situations)

Answer (score 1):

### Data preparation

Here's a workaround to make work `mlogit::mlogit` together with `partykit::mob()` function based on Achim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366612/partykitmob-mlogit-error-no-suitable-fitting-function-specified/67393726#67393726). First, we need to use the data in the wide format to properly parse the score functions when the `partykit::mob()` function extracts it using `estfun`. Additionally, I generated a partition variable (`z1`) at the level of individuals (which was a mistake I made in my original question (!)).

```
# First generate the choice variable in the wide format
df$y_wide<- with(df, 
                 ave(x = altern * y , 
                     by = id_choice, 
                     FUN = max))
# drop the long formate choice variable
df <- subset( df, select = -y )
# reshape the data.
df_wide <- reshape(df, 
                   idvar = "id_choice", 
                   timevar = "altern", 
                   direction = "wide",
                   v.names = c("x1", "x2"))
# Add the partition variable
set.seed(777)
# Here I am generating a partition variable at the individual level.
# I made a mistake in my original question generating the partition variable 
# at the choice situation level.
df_wide$z1 <- rep(rnorm(max(df_wide$id_ind)),each = 3)


head(df_wide)
#    id_ind id_choice y_wide        x1.1        x2.1         x1.2       x2.2       x1.3       x2.3         z1
# 1       1         1      1  1.58678880  0.11887832 -0.937965347  1.1574249 -0.5115044 -1.9066752  0.4897862
# 4       1         2      2  1.07936568 -0.37267925 -0.009203032  1.6515037  0.8704740 -0.8255865  0.4897862
# 7       1         3      3 -0.63860401 -0.09459502 -0.071679538  1.5687933  0.3982633  1.4573579  0.4897862
# 10      2         4      3  0.29141345 -0.09107974  1.632831160  0.9292550 -1.1932723  0.7709262 -0.3985414
# 13      2         5      1  1.96762438 -0.16373709 -0.479859282 -0.6704213  1.1097809  0.6034819 -0.3985414
# 16      2         6      3 -0.02583477 -0.44004183 -1.255129594  1.1092828  1.3094933  1.8424720 -0.3985414
```

### Implementing the MOB algorithm together with `mlogit`.

#### 1st stage: The fit function `my_fit_for_mlogit()`.

Tweaking the fit function supplied to `partykit::mob`, we present the data in wide format, but we "format it" to be used by `mlogit::mlogit()` by using the `dfidx()` function. This way to proceed means that there is a hidden `stats::reshape()` process working behind the scenes, so if the data set is huge, this will probably slow down the overall process.

```
library(mlogit)
library(partykit)
#### First define the function sketched by Achim in his comment.
my_fit_for_mlogit <- function(y, 
                              x = NULL, 
                              start = NULL, 
                              weights = NULL, 
                              offset = NULL, ...) {

  #First declare dfidx data 
  xy <- cbind(y,x)
  # Properly declare the data to be used by mlogit.
  d <- dfidx(data    = xy, 
             shape   = "wide", 
             choice  = "y_wide",
             varying = 2:7,
             sep     = ".",
             idx     = list(c("id_choice", "id_ind")), 
             idnames = c(NA, "altern"))
  
  # fit mlogit using data equal "d"
  model <- mlogit::mlogit(formula = y_wide ~ x1 + x2|1 ,
                         data    =  d)

    return(model)
}
```

#### 2nd stage: Using the `partykit::mob()` function

Below we invoke the `my_fit_for_mlogit()` inside of the `mob()` function, using a very large alpha (`alpha = 0.99`) just for the sake of illustration. Here is important to note that we have to include all the explanatory variables in the wide format (e.g `x1.1 + x2.1 + x1.2`) together with the indexing variables, choice situation variable (`id_choice`), and individuals index variable (`id_ind`) and the partition variable (`z1`) is placed after the `|` symbol.

```
# the trick is to include all the variables in wide format and then
# let dfidx() do the magic INSIDE the my_fit_for_mlogit() function. 


tr <- mob(formula = y_wide ~  
                    x1.1 + x2.1 + x1.2 + 
                    x2.2 + x1.3 + x2.3 + 
                    id_choice + id_ind + 0 | z1, 
          data    = df_wide, 
          fit     = my_fit_for_mlogit,
          cluster = id_ind, 
          control = mob_control(ytype = "data.frame", 
                                xtype = "data.frame",
                                alpha = 0.99, # This is just for illustration
                                minsize = 6))

# Model-based recursive partitioning (my_fit_for_mlogit)
# 
# Model formula:
#   y_wide ~ x1.1 + x2.1 + x1.2 + x2.2 + x1.3 + x2.3 + id_choice + 
#   id_ind + 0 | z1
# 
# Fitted party:
#   [1] root
# |   [2] z1 <= 0.48979: n = 9
# |       (Intercept):2 (Intercept):3            x1            x2 
# |          -3.3989117     0.3696964     0.9647511     2.5129869 
# |   [3] z1 > 0.48979: n = 6
# |       (Intercept):2 (Intercept):3            x1            x2 
# |            45.77874     -11.51773      21.72540      31.29221 
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    1
# Number of terminal nodes: 2
# Number of parameters per node: 4
# Objective function: 4.605233
```